# Place watermark text using FPDF in PDF at pixel position (x,y)

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, watermark

I want to place watermark text in PDF using FPDF at x,y position but at specific pixels like 30px from top and 20px from left instead of x,y position provided by function

```
$this->RotatedText(35,190,'W a t e r m a r k   d e m o',45); //here 35,190 are positions for x & y but have no idea what they will be at pixels.

function RotatedText($x, $y, $txt, $angle)
{
    //Text rotated around its origin
    $this->Rotate($angle,$x,$y);
    $this->Text($x,$y,$txt);
    $this->Rotate(0);
}
```

let me know if there is a way to convert pixels to corresponding x,y position. Any idea would be appreciated

Reference : http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script9.php

Comment: There are no pixels in a PDF.

Comment: Ok, is there any way to get estimate if I want to start x,y like 1 inches from top and .5 inches from left. that would be just say something like 24,50 etc but is this a hit trial to get for accurate positions

Comment: FPDF uses millimeters by default, so you can convert inches to mm to get the x, y values.